# Can't get OAuth 2 Scope. It is not set. Quickbook

Tags: oauth-2.0, scope, authorization, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have successfully integrated Quickbook accounting APIs with the Development Keys and Credentials. Moreover, when I put Production Keys and Secret, I got an error with status code (403), and later I got to know that is because of scopes.
I noticed there is a function called "getScope()" to check the token scopes. I went to try that and get the following error:

> Can't get OAuth 2 Scope. It is not set.

I even tried using access and refresh tokens from the API playground. Still, the error is there.
Here is my code snippet:

```
$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
        'auth_mode' => 'oauth2',
        'ClientID' => $quickBookData->client_id,
        'ClientSecret' => $quickBookData->client_secret,
        'accessTokenKey' => $quickBookData->access_token,
        'refreshTokenKey' => $quickBookData->refresh_token,
        'QBORealmID' => $quickBookData->realm_id,
        'baseUrl' => "production",
    ));
    $OAuth2LoginHelper = $dataService->getOAuth2LoginHelper();
    $scopes = $OAuth2LoginHelper->getScope();
```